# Abrir outra página em modal JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, mvc, telerik

eu estou com um problema que não consigo resolver de nenhuma forma.
Bem, tenho um projeto em Asp.NET MVC da seguinte forma:

Model

```
public class Objeto
    {
        public Objeto()
        {
        }
        public Objeto(string nome, double valor, double percentual)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Valor = valor;
            Percentual = percentual;
        }
        public string Nome{ get; set; }
        public double Valor { get; set; }
        public double Percentual { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Dados(Objeto teste)
      {
          return View(dados);
      }
}
```

View Index:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Dados", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Sucesso()", OnComplete = "unlockPage()", OnBegin = "lockPage()", OnFailure = "ajaxHandleError" }, new { @id = "meuForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Valor)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Percentual)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Percentual)
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
}
```

View Dados

```
<label>Os dados inseridos foram:</label>
@Model.Nome
<br />
@Model.Valor
<br />
@Model.Percentual
<br />
```

Bem, o que preciso é apresentar a `View Dados` dentro da `View Index` em uma `popup` ou `modal`, usando `Jquery` ou `Telerik`, mas os dados precisam vir do `controller`, previamente enviados via `POST` pela página `Index`.

Comment: mas vc precisa apresentar isso em uma nova guia?

Comment: não, preciso apresentar isso na mesma tela que chamou, no caso a index, e também não posso perder os dados da página que chamou. No caso eu deveria usar Ajax, enviar os dados via POST para o controlador e retornar para a página que a chamou montando um popup ou modal do Telerik apresentando a página de dados. O problema é como fazer isso.

Comment: comentei abaixo o uso de viewbag, conhece?

Comment: você adicionou o `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`? se sim pode pegar o retorno da requisição Ajax no método `Sucesso(response)`, então você irá trabalhar com o conteudo do response (retorno da sua Controller) e chamar a API do seu Modal... porém a declaração do método é sem os `()`, ficando `OnSuccess = "Sucesso"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não tenho conhecimento da sua UI, e você deixou em aberto a tecnologia a ser usada para abrir o Dialogo, então vou focar na requisição Ajax em si.

**Model**

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class Objeto
    {
        public Objeto()
        {
        }

        public Objeto(string nome, double valor, double percentual)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Valor = valor;
            Percentual = percentual;
        }

        public string Nome{ get; set; }
        public double Valor { get; set; }
        public double Percentual { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Dados(Objeto teste)
        {           
            return Json(teste);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.Objeto
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" ></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/master/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" ></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Dados", "Home", new AjaxOptions { 
            OnSuccess = "onSucess"
        }, new { @id = "meuForm" }))
        {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome)
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Valor)
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Percentual)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Percentual)
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        }
        <script>
            var onSucess = function (response) {
                alert(
                    "Rcebi com sucesso os seguintes dados: \n" +
                    "Nome: " + (response.Nome || "Não Informado") + "\n" +
                    "Valor: " + response.Valor + "\n" +
                    "Percentual: " + response.Percentual
                );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Você pode conferir o exemplo acima funcionando no seguinte [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m9rCzn)

Note que inclui o script `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` na view, sem ele o Ajax.BeginForm não funciona da maneira esperada. também adicionei o método de sucesso `onSucess` no JavaScript.

Utilizei um `JsonResult` para retornar um `Json` como resposta, fiz isto devido a limitação do DotNetFiddle em não poder ter duas Views, mas você pode retornar um `ActionResult` sem problemas.

No exemplo abaixo estou realizando apenas um `alert()`, mas você pode facilmente utilizar o Framework que desejar,

Segue um exemplo com o [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) e usando como retorno uma `ActionResult`.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Dados(Objeto teste)
{           
    return View(teste);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var onSucess = function (response) {
    var dialogo = $(response);
    dialogo.dialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque você não usa viewbag?

```
 ViewBag.variavelQueVoceQuerMandarParaAView = "teste";
```

na tela você usa ela assim:

```
@ViewBag.variavelQueVoceQuerMandarParaAView
```

Comment: Na verdade o código apresentado é apenas um exemplo do original. Não posso usar a ViewBag, pois preciso enviar os dados da página Index de preferencia via Ajax para o Controlador para serem validados, e depois retornar como um popup ou modal do Telerik com a página Dados, sem perder outros possíveis dados da View que chamou.

Comment: se vc usar Ajax, no success vc pode fazer o modal aparecer, seria assim?

Comment: Não vou nem postar isso como resposta pois não é indicado, mas, você pode utilizar o `@TempData["variavelQueVoceQuerMandarParaAView"]`